# Scanner wont put inside Objekt arrayList

Tags: java

My problem is that my scanner wont go inside the loop and create the new objets(Ansat) inside børnehave ArrayList.

The text inside the txt file is:

ansat Casper Kern 5858 5858

ansat Trine Olsen 4747 4747

```
public class Load {

File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Ejer\\IdeaProjects\\tableSelv\\src\\Database");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

public Load() throws FileNotFoundException {

}

public void LoadAll(Børnehave børnehave) throws FileNotFoundException {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String temp = scanner.next();
    if (temp.equals("ansat")) {
        børnehave.getAnsatArrayList().add(
                new Ansat(parsePropertiesString(scanner.next()),
                        parsePropertiesString(scanner.next()),
                        parsePropertiesString(scanner.next()),
                        parsePropertiesString(scanner.next())
                )
        );

    }
    if (temp.equals("barn")) {
        børnehave.getBørnArrayList().add(
                new Barn(parsePropertiesString(scanner.next()),
                        parsePropertiesString(scanner.next()),
                        parsePropertiesString(scanner.next()),
                        parsePropertiesString(scanner.next())
                )
        );

    }
}
```

}

```
public StringProperty parsePropertiesString(String s) {

    StringProperty p = new SimpleStringProperty();
    p.setValue(s);
    return p;
}
```

}

```
public class Ansat {
    StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("","firstName","");
    StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty("","lastName","");
    StringProperty password = new SimpleStringProperty("","password","");
    StringProperty birthday = new SimpleStringProperty("","birthday","");

    public Ansat(StringProperty firstName, StringProperty lastName, StringProperty password, StringProperty birthday) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }
```

Comment: I have many problems.  I don't post them on the internet.  Specifically not on StackOverflow.  StackOverflow is for questions.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Off topic, but I highly recommend using English when naming, as it immensely helps the next developer who doesn't understand Danish.

Comment: Hint: a ***question*** consists of a) your code, (you got that covered,) b) a specific sequence of steps to follow, c) the observed results, d) the expected results.

Comment: Perhaps local classes can't refer to things outside them. No idea though, just a hypothesis.